# Check if elements in first row in 2d array are the same

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, element

I'm looping through a 2d array. To check if the first row elements are the same/equal. I'm having an issue pulling this off. Below is what I have so far.

```java
public void checkMatch(Values[][] val){
        //TODO check elements in 2d array for matches
        for(int i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < val[i].length; j++){
                if(val[i][0].equals(val[i][1]) && val[i][0].equals(val[i][2])){
                    System.out.println("Match");

                }else {
                    System.out.println("No Match");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue/error?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```java
public void checkMatchRows(Values[][] val){
        for(int i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < val[j].length -1; j++){
                if(val[i][0] == val[i][1] && val[i][1] == val[i][2]){
                    System.out.println("Match");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("No Match");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```